# i am having an error with "create-nuxt-app" command creating a Nuxt project when adding Vuetify and errors are given bellow

Tags: nuxt.js

build environment--

Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`

RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`

'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! fibers@4.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@4.0.2 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Meherab\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-01-28T16_59_33_311Z-debug.log

Comment: Can you share the contents of  C:\Users\Meherab\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-01-28T16_59_33_311Z-debug.log (removing any sensitive info if need be)

Comment: actually i deleted the logs and followed several procedures to solve the  problems and my problems solved using the method found in the link https://medium.com/@sabbir.study/adding-vuetify-2-0-in-a-existing-nuxt-js-project-dba8a71f198d  but i have to add vuetify manually cant add vuetify with the command "create-nuxt-app"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help windows users:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools    
npm install --global node-gyp
```